# Android GCM , getting unauthorized error 401 gcm php,

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on Android GCM project, for testing I am using [Device to device](http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142) project. I have a shared server for GCM server implementation. I checked this application through Google Browser API, Server API key

> [image]

but I am always getting

```
"unauthorized error 401 ".
```

Comment: Please check you have enabled Google Cloud messaging services for android in your Google cloud console

Comment: you need to use browser key and make sure that Google Cloud Messaging for android is enabled.

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging for android is enabled.

Comment: Thanks guys,,, i was doing a silly mistake, using wrong Key

Comment: @BirajZalavadia: Requires "Key for browser apps (with referers)" not browser key.